# Why pivotTable dont update after using RefreshAll or .PivotCache.Refresh - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, powerpivot, sap-erp

In resume, It's an extract from SAP ERP, copy/paste in a table, this table is treated by Power Query and exported to a Pivot Table.

I'm doing a dashboard with VBA + PowerQuery + SAP ERP data, my doubt is in the VBA part, after Copy and Paste information of SAP ERP on Excel, I tried to Running a code **ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll** but it's not working, I tried this: [Link](https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/run-a-macro-when-a-specific-cell-changes-in-excel_1592.html)
but it doesn't work too.

I've tried this too: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132156/excel-vba-refreshall-not-updating-pivot-tables) and still doesn't work.

The code and the file are in my gitHub [Link](https://github.com/Hiemer23/VBA_Problem)

Comment: It's better to post information within the question instead of external hyperlink, otherwise the question will have no interest for future visitors if the external hyperlink disappears.​

Comment: always post snippet not link of what you've tried. the context always matters

Answer (score 0):

Change the Query properties window, you need to uncheck the "Enable background refresh

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrR-FwEXjGM

Comment: It's better to post information within the question instead of external hyperlink, otherwise the question will have no interest for future visitors if the external hyperlink disappears.​